# Get Json from php jquery Ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

Php file

```
<?php global $ajax_recieve;
    if(isset($_POST['values'])){
        $ajax_recieve = $_POST['values'];
    }
    $result = mysqli_query($read_info,"SELECT Namn FROM information WHERE Namn LIKE ('".$ajax_recieve.'%")";
    $resultSet = array();
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
        $resultSet[] = array( 'Name'=> $row['Namn']);
    }
    $json = json_encode($resultSet);
    echo $json;
?>
```

JS file

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#search').on('input', function() {
        var inputSearch = $('#search').val();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            datatype: 'json',
            url: "createJSON_list.php",
            data: {values: inputSearch},
            success: function(response){
                $.each(response, function(){
                    $('#json_datalist').append(response[0]);
                    console.log(response[0]);
                });
            }
        });     
    });
});
```

I cannot see value in console.log. Or I get only last data from database. I need a array which must be append to a html datalist as an array.

Comment: you have some errors  in your code (maybe just the question) `"SELECT Namn FROM information WHERE Namn LIKE (‘“.$ajax_recieve.’%”)”` these are MS Currly quotes.  You can see by the color of the code that there is a quoting issue in there.  In PHP that would be a syntax error.

Comment: This is also wide open to SQLInjection `$ajax_recieve = $_POST['values'];`  And if that if condition around it fails, your query runs but the above variable is undefined in that case.  And ..... And I think this parentheses `LIKE ('` is wrong.  Not sure if it's an error but it isn't needed, and I've never seen one used there before.

Comment: Hi changed. But it is not in my code. maybe i get it by copy and paste. Php code working good

Comment: If it worked "good" you wouldn't be here, would you.  You understand that this will give you only the first row `console.log(response[0]);` and to get the whole dataset you have to use `response`, Sorry I had to ask.

Comment: And you also spelled name wrong in the code `SELECT Namn FROM`  and `$resultSet[] = array( 'Name'=> $row['Namn']);`  not sure if it's that way in the DB, but I would fix that.

Comment: console.log(response[0]); It's only a test if I get something back from php

Comment: Sorry, I have like a built in debugger in my head now ... lol.  Besides the things I mentioned I don't see anything wrong with your code.  If you get only some rows back, the error is in either your query logic, input data, or Db data.  It cant be a code error if it works.

Comment: $row['Namn'] It is name of my column in database(Namn)

Comment: Updateif(isset($_POST['values'])){

            $ajax_recieve = $_POST['values'];
            $ajax_recieve = mysqli_real_escape_string($ajax_recieve);
        }
$result = mysqli_query($read_info, "SELECT Namn FROM information WHERE Namn LIKE'".$ajax_recieve."%'");

Comment: Now I get typeError cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'length' in on this line $.each(response, function(){

Answer (score 0):

Solved

contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
Removed this row and changed this

```
    $.each(response, function(key,Val){$('#json_datalist').append(“<value=‘“+Val.Name”’+”>”);
```